# Here is a linear algebra problem from an interview and I have no clue.

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix C of size n$\times$n is symmetric . Zero is a simple eigenvalue of C. The associated eigenvector is q. For  $\epsilon$>0, the equation $Cx+\epsilon x=d$ in x, where x and d are n-dimensional Column vectors and d is known, has a solution that depends on  $\epsilon$. Call this solution  $x(\epsilon)$. Express $ \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \epsilon x(\epsilon)$ in terms of vectors q and d.

I have some inspirations:

1. When $\epsilon \to 0$, $\epsilon q$ also comes to $0$. So we have: $C(x+q)+\epsilon (x+q)=d$
2. Since C is a symmetrix matrix, we use diagonalization like: $U\Lambda U^Hx+\epsilon x=d$

But to be honest, I have no clue on this and it bothers me a lot. I can't figure out how to use these conditions we have.

Thank you for reading my question!

Could you give me some clues on this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do not use images to convey information not otherwise available in your post. [See here for why it is bad practice to do so](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @YIFan To be honest, I tried some methods but I don't think they make sense. I never meet problems like this before.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin
Of course, I think you are right.

Comment: @snowman no problem, that's quite normal, but it's good to add some of your own thoughts to the question (as I see you have done) to help others know roughly where your thought process is at so we can help you better! Also, some users think questions that only have a problem statement seem low-effort and may be tempted to close them, so adding your own efforts show people that you've really thought about it before asking. :)

Comment: @YiFan Sure, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume here that $C$ is a *real* symmetric matrix.

**HINT**: We assume $q$ is a unit vector. Apply the Spectral Theorem to write
$$C+\epsilon I = \epsilon qq^\top + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\lambda_i + \epsilon) v_iv_i^\top,$$
where $q,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$ form an orthonormal basis. Then
$$(C+\epsilon I)^{-1} = \frac1{\epsilon} qq^\top + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac1{\lambda_i + \epsilon} v_iv_i^\top.$$
Of course, we assume $\epsilon>0$ small enough so that no $\lambda_i+\epsilon$ becomes $0$.
Can you finish now?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wrote an answer based on your hint:
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1057706/snowman

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[Ted Shifrin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71348/ted-shifrin)! Here is my answer:

First,
$(C+\epsilon I)x = d$, so $x=(C+\epsilon I)^{-1}d$ and then $\epsilon x=\epsilon (C+\epsilon I)^{-1}d$

As said by Ted,
$$(C+\epsilon I)^{-1} = \frac1{\epsilon} qq^\top + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac1{\lambda_i + \epsilon} v_iv_i^\top.$$
So we have:
$$\epsilon x=\epsilon(C+\epsilon I)^{-1}d = qq^\top d + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda_i + \epsilon} v_iv_i^\top d$$
The final result would be:
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\epsilon x = qq^\top d$$